# Given this model, how to delete a nested array item with updateOne (mongoose)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to remove an array item with "updateOne" method but my query is not matching the right record in the model structure that I have. Given an email, I would like to find the array item with the provided email and pulls it out, remove it. (There is no array item with the same email)

My model is like so:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var teamMemberModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     _id: false,
    "email": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "minlenght": 5,
        "maxheight": 50
    },
    "name": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "minlenght": 5,
        "maxheight": 256
    },
    "role": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "minlenght": 20,
        "maxheight": 256
    },
    "twitter": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "minlenght": 1,
        "maxheight": 100
    },
    "facebook": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "minlenght": 1,
        "maxheight": 100
    },
    "linkedin": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "minlenght": 1,
        "maxheight": 100
    },
});

var teamModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "title": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "minlenght": 5,
        "maxheight": 20
    },
    "headline": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "minlenght": 5,
        "maxheight": 30
    },
    "description": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "minlenght": 5,
        "maxheight": 80
    },
    "members": [teamMemberModelSchema]
}, { collection: 'team' });

teamModelSchema.set('collection', 'team');
mongoose.model('team', teamModelSchema)
```

And the approach that I am trying is the following:

```js
module.exports.removeMember = function (req, res) {
  const email = req.params.email;
  const query = { "members.email": email };
  const pull = { $pull: { "members.$.email": email } };

  try {
    var message = teamMsg.teamMemberRemoveSuccess;

    TeamModel.updateOne(query, pull);

    responseUtilities.sendJSON(res, false, { message: message });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    responseUtilities.sendJSON(res, err, { message: err.message });
  }
};
```

It executes with no errors, but nothing is updated.

I have tried some others alternatives with "FindOneAndUpdate" and "FindOneAndRemove" but, I could not find a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you check if your query `{ "members.email": email }` return something ?

Comment: yes, I did. but nothing is deleted/updated.

Comment: Do you wanted to pull the member entire object where `{ "members.email": email }` or do you just wanted to remove the field email from member object ?

Comment: @whoami I want to remove the entire member with the provided email and NOT just its email field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findOneAndUpdate` with `$pull`  operator for this task.

For removing items from an array of documents you can check MongoDb [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents)

You need to use `await` or `then` block to query. I used await, and made the function asynchronous by adding `async` keyword. We also need empty query object.

I also added the `new: true` option, to return the updated object to check if the item is deleted.

You need to handle the case where no document matches, I added a TODO for you.

```js
module.exports.removeMember = async function(req, res) {
  const email = req.params.email;
  const query = {};

  const pull = {
    $pull: {
      members: {
        email: email
      }
    }
  };

  const options = {
    new: true
  };

  try {
    var message = teamMsg.teamMemberRemoveSuccess;

    const result = await TeamModel.updateOne(query, pull, options);

    console.log(result);

    if (!result) {
      //TODO: return 400-Bad Request or 404 - Not Found
    } else {
      responseUtilities.sendJSON(res, false, { message: message });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    responseUtilities.sendJSON(res, err, { message: err.message });
  }
};
```

Comment: it worked fine! thank you very much! why did you empty query object? would you please explain that? I had tried this same solution but I had put this query => const query = { "members.email": email };

Comment: @OlavoAlexandrino becase the query seems to be used for top level document, so in this case it must be empty. I guess you can find more info about this in the docs in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

give this query a try:

```
db.collection.update(
    { 'members.email': 'email@address' },
    { $pull: { members: { email: 'email@address' } } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `update()` method and `async/await`:

```
module.exports.removeMember = async function (req, res) {

    const email = req.params.email;
    console.log(`email = ${email}`)   // Make sure correct value is coming thru

    const query = { "members.email": email };
    const pull = { $pull: { "members.$.email": email } };
    const options = { multi: true }

    try {

        var message = teamMsg.teamMemberRemoveSuccess;

        await TeamModel.update( query, pull, options );


        responseUtilities.sendJSON(res, false, { "message": message });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        responseUtilities.sendJSON(res, err, { "message": err.message });
    }
};
```